# Unable to install laravel 4 using composer on ubuntu

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

```
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/$ sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/$ cd /home/user
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user$ sudo wget https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user$ unzip master.zip
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user$ cd laravel-master
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user/laravel-master$ sudo composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user/laravel-master$ sudo composer update
PHP Warning:  require(/home/user/laravel-master/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/laravel-master/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/user/laravel-master/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/user/laravel-master/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error
[RuntimeException]
Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(/home/user/laravel-master/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/laravel-master/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/user/laravel-master/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/user/laravel-master/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user/laravel-master$ sudo composer dump-autoload -o
Generating autoload files
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user/laravel-master$ sudo composer update
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in /home/user/laravel-master/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error
[RuntimeException]
Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in
/home/user/laravel-master/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46
```

I've spent quite a lot of time playing around and couldn't find any documentation on this problem, I will be honest and say I don't know enough about composer to solve it.

**EDIT**

I tried the following which was suggested in the answers, without any luck.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user$ sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel master
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.0.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v4.0.0)
    Loading from cache
Created project in laravel
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user$ ls
master
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user$ cd master
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user/master$ ls
app  artisan  bootstrap  composer.json  CONTRIBUTING.md  phpunit.xml  public  readme.md  server.php
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user/master$ sudo composer install --no-scripts
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user/master$ ls
app  artisan  bootstrap  composer.json  CONTRIBUTING.md  phpunit.xml  public  readme.md  server.php
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user/master$ sudo composer dump-autoload -o
Generating autoload files
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user/master$ ls
app  artisan  bootstrap  composer.json  CONTRIBUTING.md  phpunit.xml  public  readme.md  server.php  vendor
ubuntu@ip-10-252-31-19:/home/user/master$ sudo tail /var/log/nginx/error.log
2013/06/06 15:50:56 [error] 20042#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in /home/user/master/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46"
 while reading response header from upstream, client: w.x.y.z, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "dom.com"
```

Comment: Strange thing is that after `composer install` You have no `vendor` directory. Dunno why, but composer didn't download any package.  

And, You're using composer with `sudo`. Maybe try running it as a regular user?

Comment: Detailed tutorial: [How to install Laravel 4 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Composer](http://www.dev-metal.com/install-laravel-4-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) including Apache & mod_rewrite setup and PHP installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like your composer isn't working which is usually a characteristic of a non-compatible PHP version. What version is your PHP ? Laravel requires >= 5.3.7

Try updating PHP and re-running composer by issuing the following commands

-add PHP5 to your apt-get repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

-update your apt-get

```
sudo apt-get update
```

-reinstall PHP, making sure you overwrite your current version with the new one !

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm php5-cli php5-cgi
```

Restart nginx just to be sure then re run composer install in the laravel directory.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue lately. Just run composer with `--no-scripts` flag.

`composer update --no-scripts`

Comment: I am still getting the Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' error even when using the --no-scripts flag

Comment: I was getting the error: `[RuntimeException] Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Bkwld\Croppa\CroppaServiceProvider' not found in`... `--no-scripts` fixed it

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 7 after Laravel error `Class 'Bkwld\Croppa\ServiceProvider' not found`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one liner script to install Laravel 4 on Ubuntu with PHP unit http://irventu.com/installing-laravel-4-with-phpunit-composer/

Comment: The link is dead. Please consider replacing with web archive, if available.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this is what worked for me:

- Backup your composer.json
- Edit comooser.json and remove the whole "scripts" block
- Save
- composer install
- Restore original composer.json
- composer update

Seems like we don't have all the dependencies needed to run artisan on a bare install, but once everything has been fetched by composer, it runs fine.

Comment: radmen's answer is much better and less "hackish" than mine, --no-scripts definitely does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run `composer update` instead of first running `composer install`?

I had this problem when I tried getting my existing project running on a different PC.

Once I pulled my project git down I tried to do a `composer update` instead of first running `composer install` which gave me the same issue.

Once I had run the `composer install` command my project downloaded and installed the various required dependencies without any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try composer update instead of composer install. Per the docs http://laravel.com/docs/installation there is a  easier way to install laravel by running the command sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel nameofproject

Comment: The official installation guideline is really crappy and does NOT work out-of-the-box. I know, this sounds weird, but is true.

Answer (score 0):

After running phpinfo, I noticed "--disable-mbregex" was part of the PHP configuration, meaning PHP was not compiled with the mbregex extension.  My error logs were showing "Call to undefined function mb_regex_encoding".

Once PHP was recompiled with mb_regex_encoding, the issue went away.